# How to verify if file is encrypted after locking device?

Tags: ios, iphone, security, encryption

I need to protect a file with user data, however I can't really verify if built-in iOS mechanism works. I implemented data protection in my app by:

1. Enabling Data Protection in AppId
2. Updating provisioning profiles
3. Adding Data Protection to entitlements.plist (entry: com.apple.developer.default-data-protection = NSFileProtectionComplete)
4. Setting attribute FileProtectionComplete on my file
5. Turning on passcode on iPhone

I was able to confirm, that this attribute is set properly. However, I tried to lock device, wait about 1 minute and access file through iExplorer or by downloading app container from Xcode->Devices and every time I'm able to get non-encrypted content.

I wonder if it's a matter of debug build or not. Is there any way to download encrypted file to confirm that data protection really works (without jailbreaking)?

Comment: Since you have enabled your device to trust your computer it has an escrow key bag, which enables it to access the unencrypted contents of your device. https://www.apple.com/business/docs/iOS_Security_Guide.pdf

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks! Is there any way to download encrypted file to confirm that data protection really works (without jailbreaking)?